# Issue with the usage of external tables

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle19c, external-tables

I have a PLSQL ABC(example name) application that uses external table. A brief overview of the application is as follows.

The application uses a log pool on the unix server, a file(containing some records) is placed by another application in the log pool at some random time daily,  this file is used by the ABC application by a oracle JOB (which occurs every 10 min) and is renamed to Progress.txt(example name). There are some external tables that load the data from the renamed file (Progress.txt) and perform the read operation from the file, correspondingly generates some files like Progress.log, Progress.bad(for bad records) based on the evaluations that we perform on the files we place the records into different directories like good records to a file with named "good" directory and bad records or records with errors to bad directories. Once the evaluation is complete the renamed file is named back to the original name.

**How can I achieve this functionality without renaming the original file?**

```
    --------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Procedure PR_IMPORT_AUDIT_LOG
--------------------------------------------------------
set define off;

  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "ABC"."PR_IMPORT_AUDIT_LOG" 
AS

   --CURSOR CUR_FILE_LIST,  is loaded with correct file names from the external table
   --EXT_TAB_IMPORT_FILE_LIST (This external table searches the logpool dir for any files present)

   --CURSOR CUR_WRONG_FILES_LIST,  is loaded with incorrect file names from the external table
   

   V_INSERT_TIMESTAMP   TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    

    --CHECK IF EXISTS NOT ALLOWED FILENAMES
    FOR REC_FILE_LIST IN CUR_WRONG_FILES_LIST
    LOOP
      --SEND ERROR MAIL
      DECLARE
         V_SUBJECT   VARCHAR2(255)   := 'ABC: Import of "'||REC_FILE_LIST.FNAME||'" is raising an error';
         V_BODY      VARCHAR2(10000) := 'Hi,' || chr(10) || chr(10) || 'during the import of the file "'||REC_FILE_LIST.FNAME||'" the following errors have occurred:';
      BEGIN

         V_BODY := V_BODY || chr(10) ||'- Error 020 = Wrong file name';  
         V_BODY := V_BODY || chr(10) || chr(10) || 'Please contact the respective IT system for correction. ';   

         SEND_MAIL('AL_IMPORT_ERROR_HANDLING',V_SUBJECT,V_BODY);
      END;     
      
      --MOVE FILE TO ERROR FOLDER
      UTL_FILE.FRENAME('ABC_AUDITLOG', REC_FILE_LIST.FNAME, 'ABC_IMPORTBAD', REC_FILE_LIST.FNAME, TRUE); 
      
    END LOOP;
    
    FOR REC_FILE_LIST IN CUR_FILE_LIST -- This cursor contains all valid file name. How can I make the filename in this iteration avaialble to the external table to so that they know current file name under process.
    LOOP
      --RENAME FILE IN inProgress.txt
      UTL_FILE.FRENAME('ABC_AUDITLOG', REC_FILE_LIST.FNAME, 'ABC_AUDITLOG', 'inProgress.txt', TRUE);  
      
      --Perform some business logic
      
      --remove inProgress.bad
      BEGIN
         UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('ABC_AUDITLOG','inProgress.bad');
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            IF SQLCODE = -29283 -- suppresses no file found exception
            THEN
               NULL;
            ELSE
               RAISE;
            END IF;
      END;         
      --remove inProgress.log      
      BEGIN
         UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('ABC_AUDITLOG','inProgress.log');
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            IF SQLCODE = -29283 -- suppresses no file found exception
            THEN
               NULL;
            ELSE
               RAISE;
            END IF;
      END;   
      
      COMMIT;
      
    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   --send some error email      
END;

/
```

**The cursor CUR_FILE_LIST contains all valid file name. How can I make the filename in this iteration available to the external table to so that they know current file name under process without renaming the original file.**

example of external table that uses the renamed file(inProgress.txt)

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table EXT_TAB_AUDIT_LOG
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE ABC.EXT_TAB_AUDIT_LOG 
   (    --column definitions
   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY ABC_AUDITLOG
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
  
  STRING SIZES ARE IN CHARACTERS       
            LOGFILE 'inProgress.log'
            BADFILE 'inProgress.bad'
            DISCARDFILE 'inProgress.dis'
            FIELDS 
               (    
               --field names from the file
               )               
               
                         )
      LOCATION
       ( 'inProgress.txt'
       )
    )
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED ;
```

The issue is that:
• when AL import failed, not one record is imported.
•error delta files are empty
•the original AL file disappears! Its not moved to a subfolder (good or bad folders). And after another 10 min procedure starts, There is not way to access the original file name (which was renamed to inProgress.txt).

Renaming is a problem because the original file name is lost in case of failure and there is no way to check which file was lost.

```
Procedure PR_INSERT_AUDIT_LOG_FROM_FILE returned the following error:

ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout

ORA-29400: data cartridge error

KUP-04039: unexpected error while trying to find file inProgress.txt in /opt/app/logpool/
```

Comment: You could maybe use the preprocessor feature to run a script that identifies the relevant file and cats it; though you'd still need a dummy file to exist and you'd need to read the security warnings around it. It isn't clear what is currently renaming the file, or how it knows when/where to look, so can't be more specific really.

Comment: There is a procedure which evaluation of the records of the file by renaming the original file, this triiggers external tables to populate (as external tables are looking for file with a Progress.txt name)  and then takes the data from the external table. Currently renaming helps because there may be more than one file in  the log pool, and we are renaming one at a time to specific name "Progress.txt" and deleting it and iterate through all the files and repeat the process.

Comment: So why do you need to change how it's working?

Comment: Would have to modify process that looks for Progress.txt. Maybe copy file with Progress.txt name to another folder and have process look in that folder. You described a working situation, not a coding issue (error message, wrong results, nothing happens). No code provided for analysis, question is not appropriate for SO.